# Redirect after X clicks? ( to different/multiple links)

Tags: php

Im aware that you can't track "clicks", as they're strictly client/Visitor side. I thinks its possible to track `everytime` they do an `onclick` on my page and update the form field which get submitted. Or use `XmlHttpRequest`, but i'm not sure on where I should start with this info.

I think the best way to go would be to  to track hits `(in php)` to my `script/ webpage/button`. i'm thinking I can do this with:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['hits'] = isset($_SESSION['hits']) ? $_SESSION['hits'] + 1 : 0;
if ($_SESSION['hits'] > 100) header('Location: /whatever.php');
```

Am I on the right track with this?

Comment: Do you want to store those click count in DB ?

Comment: I do, but do remember, I only want to use this script, only 1 webpage/ 1 link. So yes I want to keep track.

Comment: @DavidsonJames can you please elaborate what do you mean by click is it visiting a page `x` times or clicking on a link  `x` times...

Comment: Clicking on a link, then the link redirects to another page. I want that continuing sequence repeated until it gets to the link of my choice. So yes, it's an link script.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use [Localstorage](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/) instead of php session

```
var clicks = localStorage.getItem('clicks');

clicks += 1;

localStorage.setItem('clicks','2');
```